# Grails / Groovy - Timeout when exporting/importing at backoffice

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, timeout

Hello fellow IT people,

I am facing an issue for quite some time which I could not understand. It actually might be really simple but I have not been able to fix it:

When I export or Import something in my **GRAILS** Backoffice (usually excel files that are treated into data for the DB) I get this:

[image: gateway timeout]

I notice that it throws the error at exact ***one minute*** which are exactly 60 000 ms.

My server.xml configuration file of **Tomcat** at /opt/tomcat/conf looks like this on Connector Tab:

[image]

I changed the connectionTimeout to 200000 just to check if there were any changes in the time it takes to throw the timeout but nothing changed, keeps throwing it at 60000ms (1 minute).

Can anyone help me with this? Is some property that I am missing ?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I ended up by figuring out that was a firewall timeout configuration at Amazon WebServices platform where I had my machine hosted **

Comment: Are you using Apache or something else in tandem with Tomcat that may apply a timeout?

Comment: I use tomcat directly at amazon linux machine. When I run tomcat in netbeans with the project the gateway timeout is NOT thrown, so I belive that's a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by figuring out that was a firewall timeout configuration at Amazon WebServices platform where I had my machine hosted